# Get full Site file listing

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-library, open-with-explorer, explorer-view

I find Sharepoint file search not so useful (sometimes what I'm looking for is there and it doesn't find it, or on the other side it shows files that are unrelated to what I'm looking for)

I've been using the "Open with Explorer" functionality to mount the Site as a drive, and then I index it (with programs that traverse the filesystem and store it in an index like locate32, `locate`, `dir /s`, ...) but that takes hours for big sites, and also this functionality will probably disappear when Internet Explorer is finally discontinued

Is there an alternative method for getting a full file listing?

Answer (score 0):

The "Export to Excel" button in the web interface downloads a .iqy file that opens in Excel and shows a full file listing. It's fast and can be searched and processed:

[image]